# if a relation is reflexive, symmetric, or transitive

Tags: relations

А = {1, 2, 3, 4}
p= {(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (1, 3), (3, 4)}

I know what reflexive, symmetric, or transitive are, I just want answer with these examples.
I think it should be transitive?

Comment: If you know what reflexive, symmetric and transitive are, then why would you think this was transitive when $(1,3)$ and $(3,4)$ but not $(1,4)$?

Answer (score 2):

It is reflexive 
$(a,a)$ for all $a\in A$

It is not symmetric as $(1,3)$ is in $p$ but $(3,1)$ is not.

It is not transitive.  If it were then $(1,3), (3,4) \implies(1,4).$
But that is not the case.

Comment: I've pasted the wrong example.  А = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} 
p= {(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)}
This is transitive, right, its not reflexive nor symmetric?

Comment: In your second example, yes, transitive, but not reflexive or symmetric.